# Wordpress output links to previous and next posts from custom query

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the advanced custom fields plugin for wordpress to create a group of custom post types that have a date set within them.

I'm trying to show the previous post, and the next post, based on the date stored in the custom field. The links need to link to posts that have a date set in the future (so don't show links to posts with dates that have gone by)/

I can get a list of all the posts that are in the future, and out put these using the following code;

```
<?php 
    $rightnow = current_time('Ymd');

    $args = array(                      
    'post_type' => 'Courses',
    'posts_per_page' => '25',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date_of_the_course_single_day',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => $rightnow,
            )
            ),
    'meta_key' => 'date_of_the_course_single_day',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',                                       
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$posts = get_posts($args); 

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
?>
    Output details of post here....
<?php   
}                   
?>
```

What I thought I could do, is the get the current post's position in the array, to then get details of the posts one before and one after... but I haven't got a clue how to do this.

I've experimented with the wordpress next_post_link and previous_post_link functions, but these seem to work based on when the post was added to wordpress, rather than based on my custom date field.

Am I going about this the complete wrong way? Any tips or pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) plus [paginate_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

```
$rightnow = current_time('Ymd');

// Query Args
$args = array(                      
    'post_type' => 'Courses',
    'posts_per_page' => '25',
    'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key' => 'date_of_the_course_single_day',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value' => $rightnow,
     ) ),
    'meta_key' => 'date_of_the_course_single_day',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',                                       
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$query = new WP_QUery( $arg ); 
$posts = $query->get_posts();

// Paginate Args
$page_args = array(
    'base'               => 'your_custom_page_url'.'%_%', // Make sure you got this current depending on your setup
    'format'             => '/%#%', // requires pretty permalinks
    'total'              => $query->max_num_pages,
    'current'            => 0,  
    'prev_text'          => __('«'),
    'next_text'          => __('»'),
);

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    // Output 
}   

echo paginate_links( $page_args );
```

You have to verify that the `base` and `format` of paginate args are correct of it won't properly worked.